# How to capture value selected from a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a simple form that I am creating using react JS. I have 2 text fields, Type & Year, and one dropdown which is car. The car dropdown is populated using a value coming from an API. The user enters text value for the first 2 fields and selects the value for car from the dropdown menu and hits add. I have another post API that captures this value. I can store and set the value for the text boxes but for the dropdown, the value of car is not getting captured and I get a null value. How can I store the value of car like I am doing for other 2 text boxes

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';

function NewCar() {

  const [type, setType] = useState("");
  const [year, setYear] = useState("");
  const [car, setCar] = useState("");
  let history = useHistory();

  const [entries,setEntries]=useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchValues();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(entries)
  }, [entries])
  
  const fetchValues = async()=>{
    const response = await axios('http://localhost:8080/cars');
    setEntries(response.data)
  }

  const onSubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/update", {
        type,
        year,
        car
      })
      .then(() => history.push("/"));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <table border="1">
      Type:{" "}
      <input
        name="type"
        value={type}
        onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      Year:{" "}
      <textarea
        name="year"
        value={year}
        onChange={(e) => setYear(e.target.value)}
      ></textarea>{" "}
      <br />
      <label for="car">Car:</label>
        <select id="car" name="car">
          {entries.map((entry) => (
             <option value={entry.name}>{entry.name}</option>
          ))}
          name="car"
          value={car}
          onChange={(e) => setCar(e.target.value)}
       </select>
      <br />
    </table>
      <button>Add</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default NewCar;
```

Comment: use onChange for select too lie you are doing with input. Select will get its value from its option.
Exarcise : Try to add some value to select and if you will find that option with that value is selected by default.

Comment: Is the "react-native" tag on this a mistake? Looks like HTML to me.

Comment: Hi @jnpdx If I'm not mistake, react and react-native have nearly identical syntaxes; the only difference is that react-native is utilized on applications. Perhaps he's using react-native.

Comment: @MohammadKhan you are correct in a sense (the React part is very similar), but the entities such as "form" "table" "br" "input" etc are all HTML entities and *not used* in React Native (unless exported from a 3rd party package of some sort).

Comment: @jnpdx Oh, I see, I understand. My mistake. I believe it would be preferable to delete the react-native tag because it isn't  the major focus of this post. Thank you for explaining or proving your to me in such a kind manner :))

Comment: deleting react-native tag

Answer (score 1):

I believe you made a mistake in your code by placing your attributes outside the select tag, it should look something like this:

```
  <select
    id="car"
    name="car"
    value={car}
    onChange={(e) => setCar(e.target.value)}
  >
    {entries.map((entry) => (
      <option value={entry.name}>{entry.name}</option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

I have this sample in which u can get the the value of a select tag or dropdown, hope you can reference from it.

```
const [dataItem, setDataItem] = useState("");

  const data = [
    {
      name: "Ford",
      year: "1903",
    },
    {
      name: "Chevy",
      year: "1904",
    },
    {
      name: "Dodge",
      year: "1905",
    },
    {
      name: "Honda",
      year: "1906",
    },
    {
      name: "Toyota",
      year: "1907",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {dataItem}
      <select
        name="dataItem"
        value={dataItem}
        onChange={(e) => setDataItem(e.target.value)}
      >
        {data.map(({name}) => (
          <option value={name}>{name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </>
  );
```

If it still went wrong, please let me know and write a comment below.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Still getting null value from the dropdown selection

Comment: hi @RiteshSinha could you give me a screenshot or picture of the results u have?

Comment: I don't see any error as such. When I check the logs for the API I have all other fields have value that I have provided but this field gets a null value. It means setCar is not able to set the value for car

Comment: I see, so basically here you are trying to edit then update the data so u are trying to get the value of the select field but showing null? am I right?

Comment: Yes, there are 3 boxes. 2 textbox and 1 dropdown. Getting values in the Car dropdown and let user select one of the listed value & let user provide values for the 2 text boxes. Once the user hit add an API is called and values are updated in database. The problem is with the above code after selecting the value from the dropdown and hitting add I get correct values for the text box but null from the dropdown selection

Comment: your solution looks correct, but somehow not able to work for my use case